# Mysql sorting of alphanumeric values without considering alphabet

Tags: mysql

In database, it store values are

```
M2345
45
M345
E21
A3
```

is there a way to sort it correctly? like

```
A3
E21
45
M345
M2345
```

Comment: I've never seen this.  It is sorted correctly, by ascii code.  Without knowing if it exists or not, it would be chaos to do this with a replace at runtime.  You could have a second column for sorting purposes that will expand the numeric value.  You'd run into problems, meaning time-consuming literal programming, due to things like 4 = 'four', but 40 = 'forty' (not fourzero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there can be at most one letter before the digits start, you could use a condition like this in your sorting definition:

```
ORDER BY CAST(IF(col REGEXP '^[a-z]', SUBSTRING(col, 2), col) AS SIGNED)
```

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have a replace function that can handle regular expressions, otherwise that would have been very helpful at this point.

You may also want to consider storing the numeric value itself in a separate calculated field for more efficient sorting.